# How to implicitly convert Qt objects to QString?

Tags: c++, string, qt, operator-overloading

What's the best way of making *all* of the commented code below work in a standard C++/Qt way?

```
class A {
public:
    A() { }
    virtual ~A() { }
    virtual QString toString() { return "A"; }
};

class B: A {
public:
    B() { }
    ~B() { }
    QString toString() { return "B"; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    A a_;
    B b_;

    // qDebug() << a_;  // I can make this work by overloading << yes?
    // qDebug() << b_;

    // QString x = a_;  // How do I make this work?
    // QString y = b_;

    QString s = a_.toString(); // What I'm doing at present
    qDebug() << b_.toString(); // What I'm doing at present

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have a hierarchy of instances of my own Qt classes that all derive from the same base class.  I'd like to turn them into strings implicitly in a standard way to be displayed in a Qt ui:

I can do it explicitly myself as above with my own standard method like `toString` above, but it's not implicit and I'd rather follow a Qt or C++ convention as I believe there is one I'm not aware of.

The strings will eventually be displayed in Q*View controls which I believe means overloading `operator <<` won't be enough on it's own.

Comment: There's no point in defining an empty public constructor and empty public non-virtual destructor, by the way.

Comment: @GMan: Thanks, though the destructors above are `public virtual`

Comment: @Petermcg: One is, yes (I made sure my list acknowledged that), the other doesn't need to be explicitly defined though.

Comment: @GMan: Surely both destructors are public virtual and explicit is better than implicit? Most of the Qt classes in hierarchies are declared like this

Comment: @petermcg: Explicit isn't better than implicit when it doesn't add anything. When I see a declared constructor or destructor, I assume it's for a reason, but three of four of yours have no reason, and just add noise. (They also have subtle effects like technically giving your classes a non-trivial constructor).

Comment: @GMan: That explains things more clearly, thanks...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just add a so-called *conversion function*:

```
struct foo
{
    operator int() { return 5; }
};

foo f;
int i = f; // uses operator to convert to int
```

So in your case, just replace `virtual QString toString()` with `virtual operator QString()`.

---

That said, implicit operators are generally frowned-upon. Not only are casts frowned upon, but now you're allowing a cast to happen implicitly. C++0x actually allows us to tack on `explicit` to the conversion functions to make sure we explicitly cast, but I don't know which compilers support that.

I think you'd be much better off leaving what you have, and just adding:

```
// I assume qDebug() is convertible to std::ostream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const A& val)
{
    stream << val.toString(); // would need to make function const, of course

    return stream;
}
```

And leaving the rest explicit.

Comment: explicit is not new in C++0x, it was already in C++03. So all standard conforming compilers should support it.

Comment: @hmnuelner: The keyword `explicit`, sure, but its use in a conversion function is completely new, that's why we have things like the safe-bool idiom that we have to use. In C++03, its only use was in constructors.